# How to generate integers between min and max using normal distribution?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, integer, normal-distribution

I learnt that we use

```
 unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
 std::default_random_engine generator (seed);
 std::normal_distribution<double> distribution (mean_value,variance_value);
```

to generate real numbers. But I don't know how to give a range (min and max) to this generation and how to generate only integers in this scenario. In case of uniform_distribution, it is straight forward. Can anyone help please? Thanks!

Comment: `std::normal_distribution<int> distribution (mean_value,variance_value);` ?

Comment: If you want a minimum and a maximum, are you sure you actually want a normal distribution? They don't have bounds.

Comment: A normal distribution doesn't have a bounded range, so you need to do something artificial. Just get the value from the distribution and if it's outside the range you want ignore it and generate a new value.

Comment: maybe just use the [`round`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) function as shown in the [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution)?

Comment: If you use `std::normal_distribution<double>((max+min)/2, (max-min)/6)` you have a [99.73%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_deviation_and_coverage) chance of a number being in bounds.

Comment: Hmm... apparently `std::normal_distribution<int>` has an *undefined effect* (c.f. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution)). Probably best to just round the output of the rng to obtain an `int`.

Comment: Do you really want normally-distributed integers? That sounds like a contradiction in terms. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I see the point! The limits is for a specific situation, which I can limit using conditional statements. I can manage with real distribution, but it would be simple if I had integers. Thanks all!

Comment: @TrebledJ no, just use discrete distribution as I did - you have fixed number of values to sample

Comment: @PeteBecker Well, there is a truncated gaussian distribution

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Truncated gaussian usually used when you need bounds

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux -- thanks for the information. I suppose I can't get away with claiming that when I said "normal distribution" I was referring to `std::normal_distribution`. <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker You might take a look at my answer for possible solution. I think using discrete distribution is best approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could compute probabilities from normal distribution at given points, and use them for discrete sampling.

Along the lines

```
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

constexpr double PI = 3.14159265359;

static inline double squared(const double x) {
    return x * x;
}

double GaussPDF(const double x,
                const double mu,
                const double sigma) {
    return exp(-0.5 * squared((x - mu) / sigma)) / (sqrt(2.0 * PI) * sigma);
}

int SampleTruncIntGauss(const int xmin, const int xmax, const double mu, const double sigma, std::mt19937_64& rng) {
    int n = xmax - xmin + 1;
    std::vector<double> p(n);
    for (int k = 0; k != n; ++k)
        p[k] = GaussPDF(static_cast<double>(xmin) + k, mu, sigma);

    std::discrete_distribution<int> igauss{ p.begin(), p.end() };

    return xmin + igauss(rng);
}

int main() {

    int xmin = -3;
    int xmax =  5;
    int n = xmax - xmin + 1;

    double mu = 1.2;
    double sigma = 2.3;

    std::mt19937_64 rng{ 98761728941ULL };

    std::vector<int> h(n, 0);

    for (int k = 0; k != 10000; ++k) {
        int v = SampleTruncIntGauss(xmin, xmax, mu, sigma, rng);
        h[v - xmin] += 1;
    }

    int i = xmin;
    for (auto k : h) {
        std::cout << i << "   " << k << '\n';
        ++i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You could make code more optimal, I reinitialize probabilities array each time we sample, but it demonstrates the gist of the idea.

UPDATE

You could also use non-point probabilities for sampling, basically assuming that probability at integer point `x` means probability to have value in the range [x-0.5...x+0.5]. This could be easily expressed via Gaussian CDF.

```
constexpr double INV_SQRT2 = 0.70710678118;

double GaussCDF(const double x,
                const double mu,
                const double sigma) {
    double v = INV_SQRT2 * (x - mu) / sigma;
    return 0.5 * (1.0 + erf(v));
}

double ProbCDF(const int    x,
               const double mu,
               const double sigma) {
    return GaussCDF(static_cast<double>(x) + 0.5, mu, sigma) - GaussCDF(static_cast<double>(x) - 0.5, mu, sigma);
}
```

and code for probabilities would be

```
for (int k = 0; k != n; ++k) {
    p[k] = ProbCDF(xmin + k, mu, sigma);
```

Result is slightly different, but still resembles Gaussian

Comment: Thank You. This is very helpful!!

Comment: @RagTej You're welcome. If this answers your question, please accept it and lets move on